# Looping MD5 returns different values on PHP and WP7

Tags: php, windows-phone-7, hash, md5

I've been trying to integrate MD5 hashes to my WP7 app but I've noticed that the Silverlight MD5 implementation http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SilverlightMD5 does not return the same hash if I compare with PHP's MD5 result. If I hash once, the hash values are equal, but if I hash more than once, the final hash result is different. Has anyone else noticed this or any idea why this might happen, possible fix, etc?

```
PHP Code
$pwd = "pwd";
for ($i=0; $i < 2 ; $i++)
{
    $pwd = md5($pwd);
}
print $pwd;

WP7 Code
String hashpwd = "pwd";
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            String hash = hashpwd;             
            hashpwd = MD5Core.GetHashString(hash);
        }
MessageBox.Show(hashpwd);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the MD5 calculation is correct, you should have a look at the output of the first run and if they are exactly the same. For example, if PHP uses lower case characters `a`-`f`, but WP7 uses uppercase characters `A`-`F`, the second MD5 sum will be different.

Comment: You make a valid point about the case, I forgot about that. +1.

Comment: Thanks. Setting my hash results to lowercase in WP7 solved the issue!

Answer (score 4):

This will be because in WP7 you are hashing a binary representation of the first hash, whereas in PHP you are hashing an ASCII representation of it.

PHP's `md5()` function returns an ASCII string containing 32 hexadecimal digits represented in ASCII - 32 bytes. The WP7 version will (probably) be returning 16 bytes - a true binary representation of the hash.

I don't know for 100% sure, but I would be surprised if the answer to this is anything else.

Having said that, looking at the comments on [the page you linked to](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SilverlightMD5) it does look as though there have been bugs with this MD5 implementation in the past - so it may simply be a Silverlight bug.